# Can pure python script (not pyspark) run in parallel in a cluster in Azure Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to migrate my python scripts from local to run on cloud, specifically on a cluster created on **Azure Databricks**.

1. Can pure python script run in parallel (using multiple nodes in a cluster at the same time) without having to be converted into pyspark?
2. Is it possible to check whether the job is running in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. If you have submitted a spark job, you can see logs and it will show you number of executors it is using. That's how you 'll know job is running in parallel